# Select inserted text on Froala

Tags: javascript, froala

I need to select a chunk of text that was just inserted on a Froala textarea. Here's what I've tried:

```
// wrapper is used to get the outerHTML
var wrapper = $('<span/>');
var content = $('<p/>', { 'class': 'schedule' });
content.html(value); 
wrapper.append(content);
editor.froalaEditor('html.insert', wrapper.html());
editor.froalaEditor('selection.setAtEnd', $('.schedule')[0]);
```

Also tried adding a `selection.setAtStart` call; using `markers` module; adding `selection.restore`; focusing the textarea, and several other attemps, but nothing worked.

How must this be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after searching through Froala's GitHub issues I found this:

```
$('#editor').html('<p></p>');
$('#editor').froalaEditor();
var $p = $('#editor').data('froala.editor').$el.find('p:first');
$p.html('foo' + $.FroalaEditor.START_MARKER + 'bar' + $.FroalaEditor.END_MARKER);
$('#editor').froalaEditor('selection.restore');
```

(source: https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/803)

It looks like there's a special way to select inserted content and the documentation doesn't mention it.